# Spring Cloud dataflow server Custom Build for Issue #4017

Tags: kubernetes, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm following up on an issue which was fixed in SCDF as part milestone 107. Here is the [Link](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/milestone/107). Any idea when the release version or Snapshots would be available with the above milestone ?
If there're any can I get Custom Build for that version to deploy in Kubernetes? I tried with changing the release version to 2.6.1.Snapshot ,but I'm getting unresolved dependency issues.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>SCDFAdmin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>FACAdmin</name>
    <description>Custom Build SCDF project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR4</spring-cloud.version>
        <spring-cloud-dataflow.version>2.6.1-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud-dataflow.version>
        <spring-security-oauth2.version>2.3.7.RELEASE</spring-security-oauth2.version>
        <mariadb.version>2.4.1</mariadb.version>
        <kubernetes-client.version>4.10.2</kubernetes-client.version>
        <nimbus-jose-jwt.version>8.19</nimbus-jose-jwt.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dataflow-platform-cloudfoundry</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security-oauth2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
            <artifactId>kubernetes-client</artifactId>
            <version>${kubernetes-client.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
            <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>${nimbus-jose-jwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dataflow-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-dataflow.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-release</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Comment: This was addressed in 2.6.0-RC which means the latest `2.6.0` release as well as the `2.6.1-SNAPSHOT` should get the changes. What is the specific issue you refer to?

Comment: Issue is DB Credentials being exposed in kubernetes TaskDefnition page, when launching any task from SCDF. 
1. Issue [3985](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/3985)      
  
2.Issue[4017](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/4017)
I'm actually watching the first issue. But second one also seems to be same. I hope.

Comment: Hello @Rajesh2389 To hide DBCredentials read this section on enabling that feature.   https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.6.x/reference/htmlsingle/#_database_credentials_for_tasks

Comment: Hi Glenn, Thanks for the information. Currently I'm using 2.5.X version which is custom Build as I needed to add Oracle Driver dependencies. could you please let me where I could find a customBuild. When I tried to change the version to 2.6.1 i get below error.
```[WARNING] The POM for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server:jar:2.6.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available```
Also updated my pom.xml for SCDF Custom Build.

Comment: @GlennRenfro I tried the pom from spring repo. still I'm getting the same error. 
[SCDF2.6.1-Spring-Repo](https://repo.spring.io/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/PomView/libs-snapshot-local/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server/2.6.1-SNAPSHOT/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-2.6.1-20200730.133603-3.pom)